# woocommerce: How to exclude some products with specific tag ID from Woocommerce REST API

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm Working on a mobile app using the WooCommerce API and I need to exclude some products with a specific tag id from the `/products` endpoint.

There no options on the docs on how to do this! just mention excluding product by their id, not tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom filter with `woocommerce_rest_product_object_query` hook.

For example a filter with parameter `tag_exclude`:

`http://wp.test/wp-json/wc/v3/products?tag_exclude=21,24`

```php
function filter_woocommerce_rest_tag_exclude( $args, $request ) { 
    $params = $request->get_query_params();
    if(isset($params['tag_exclude'])){
      $args['tax_query'] = array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
              'terms' => explode(',', $params['tag_exclude']) ,
              'field' => 'term_id',
              'operator' => 'NOT IN',
          ),
      );
    } 
    return $args; 
}; 
add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_product_object_query", 'filter_woocommerce_rest_tag_exclude', 10, 2 );
```