# Hide products from Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a way to hide products from the Woocommmerce REST API. I can request certain products using filters, but I'm looking for a way to hide products from the API entirely.

I can modify the output of the API with register_rest_field and register_meta functions, but those add new data.

We are connecting our shop to a 3rd party and it's fetching all products, when we only need a very small percentage of those products. There is nu customization possible on their end, so was hoping to limit the visiblity of products in the API somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude products but does not look like there is a way to exclude certain products from being returned when listing all products on the site by default.

[woocommerce: How to exclude some products with specific tag ID from Woocommerce REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808663/woocommerce-how-to-exclude-some-products-with-specific-tag-id-from-woocommerce)

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products